# How to combine multiple input datasets (dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have multiple datasets and want to union the rows into one dataset in order to fit a classifier. Is there a good way to combine the input datasets?

My data consists of historical values of the stock market - and I want to use the complete data to fit only one classifier.

If I will create one big table - I will have problems with the end and start of each dataset.

For example - the last days of the first stock on the list will be used to train the classifier with the start of the second stock in the list.

Maybe I should normalize each data set before concatenating all to one data set?

Answered by usr: all the historical data that is related to training the classifier is already in the columns - so - appending all rows will be ok and will not cause problem with the first and the last days of different stocks/datasets

Comment: what is the common "primary key" between both your datasets?

Comment: When you say combine, do you mean you want a union (of rows) or a join (of columns) of the data frames?

Comment: date - but I am looking for patterns. so the key is less important. what is important is the behaviour of the last X days - and I encounter a problem when on the last X days of one stock to the first X days of the next stock

Comment: I want to combine all rows (append)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to union data frames into one, you have several options using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

- You can use `.append()`

e.g. `df = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)`

- You can also use `.concat()`. With concat you can join more than two data frames

e.g. `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)`

Here's some more information with examples: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: Yes. I see my problem. now i got it.

Comment: Yes, but there is no need. you are right - all the historical data that is related to the machine learning is already in the columns - so - appending all rows will solve it. the first and last days are not related to the problem. I have misunderstood the science in the machine learning science